# Approval Rule based off of Lines of Code in Merge Request

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, cicd

Is there a way either through something in a pipeline or through an approval rule to specify that an approval is required if a merge request has more than x lines of code?

Looked into Approval Rules but could only find rules based on folders/areas of the codebase.